# Can't get Mapkit class, method to compile

Tags: ios4, xcode4, mapkit

Can't get code to compile because of error in the 
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

method. xCode 4 says that "u" is an undeclared identifier, and so is the "*"

Here is the code in the .m file:

```
#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

@implementation WhereamiAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     // Create location manager object
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

    // There will be a warning from this line of code, ignore it for now
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    // We want all results from the Location Manager
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLHeadingFilterNone];

    // And we want it to be as accurate as possible
    // regardless of how much power it takes
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    // [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    // Tell our manager to start looking for its location immediately
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
   NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
 }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation   *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [u coordinate]; 
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250); 
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Can you please tell me what I need to do to overcome this problem and get the program to compile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation*)userLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate]; 
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250); 
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Your cut and paste missed the *serLocation* of *userLocation*.